# gridview problem...part two

Tags: xml, android, arrays, gridview

sorry for asking this question again but i didnt get much help on the last one (maybe due to the holidays or because my question was a bit confusing).  im trying to load images from the "drawable folder" into a gridview.  unlike the "hello android gridview" tutorial i dont know the name of the images being loaded into the gridview (as the images will be added by the user at runtime).  so, this array:

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
    R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
    R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
```

};

wont work, as i wont know the name of the images.  im guessing ill need to use a for...each statement but im lost after that.  thanks again for the help.  happy holidays

jason

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about gridview and using array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976225/question-about-gridview-and-using-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom adapter that will load the images into the views that become the grid cells.  Check out this tutorial:

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327

It uses a list view, but the concepts are the same.