# Displaying images from specific folder in sd card in grid view

Tags: android, gridview, android-sdcard

I had developed an application in which I have to display images from specific folder in sd card. My code is working fine but it is showing all images that are sd card. I had given selection args as my folder's name as it has been metioned the following post:
[Displaying images from a specific folder on the SDCard using a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039779/displaying-images-from-a-specific-folder-on-the-sdcard-using-a-gridview)

But, it didn't worked. Please, suggest me how to do this:
Below I am posting my code.

```
public class Album1Activity extends Activity {
static Cursor imageCursor;
static int columnIndex;
GridView gridView;
Intent in;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);
    String[] imgColumnID = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    imageCursor = managedQuery(uri, imgColumnID, null, null, 
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    columnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            String[] dataLocation = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            //String []dataLocation = {Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()};
            imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                        dataLocation, null, null, null);
            columnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            imageCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String imgPath = imageCursor.getString(columnIndex);
            in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullScreen.class);
            in.putExtra("id", imgPath);
            startActivity(in);
        }//onItemClickListener
    });
}//onCreate

public static class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    //Album1Activity act = new Album1Activity();
    public ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }//ImageAdapter
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imageCursor.getCount();
    }//getCount

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }//getItem

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }//getItemId

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView iv;
        if(convertView == null){
            iv = new ImageView(context);
            imageCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            int imageID = imageCursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            iv.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            "" +imageID));
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        }//if
        else{
            iv = (ImageView)convertView;
        }//else
        return iv;
    }//getView

}//ImageAdapter
```

}//Album1Activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for Answering late...
Below I am posting the final solution

```
public class Album3 extends Activity {
File [] mediaFiles;
File imageDir;
static GridView gridView;
ImageAdapter adapter;
Intent in;
ImageButton btncam;
String name = null;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bmpArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
ArrayList<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String>();
public static final String TAG = "Album3Activity";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    imageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+
             "/diplomat");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if((imageDir.exists()))
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid);
        mediaFiles = imageDir.listFiles();
        //Log.d("Length of images",""+mediaFiles.length);
        for(File file : mediaFiles)
        {
            bmpArray.add(convertToBitmap(file));
            fileName.add(readFileName(file));
            //Log.d(TAG + "bmpArray Size", ""+bmpArray.size());
            //Log.d(TAG, "call to convertToBitmap");
        }//for

        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, bmpArray, fileName);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED
                , Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/diplomat")));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullScreen.class);
            in.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    }//if
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.no_media);
    }
}//onCreate

public static Bitmap convertToBitmap(File file) 
{
    URL url = null;
    try 
    {
        url = file.toURL();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, e1.toString());
    }//catch

    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try
    {
       bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
       //bmp.recycle();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Exception: "+e.toString());
    }//catch
    return bmp;
}//convertToBitmap

public String readFileName(File file){
    String name = file.getName();
    return name;
}//readFileName
}//class
```

Comment: what is the use of filenames?

Comment: @Nitish : Hello, your codes only show media files in folder `/diplomat` right? so can not show the other media files in different folder located in sdcard, correct?

Comment: @Nitish what for videos?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**Uri.parse("path to sdcard folder")**

method

Answer (score 0):

Your linked answer already has the answer. Use the selection argument correctly.

```
cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
    **new String[] {"%myimagesfolder%"},**  
    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code ur fetching all the images from gallery try this one

```
File sdImageMainDirectory ;
String imageName ;
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "MYPICS" + File.separator);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }

ImageView camera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

cam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageName = "MyPic.png";
                sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, imageName);
                i++;
                Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                // startCameraActivity();
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case 0:
             finish();
            break;

        case -1:
            files = root.listFiles();
            count = files.length;
            try {

                ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        200, 200);
                image.setLayoutParams(vp);
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                image.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                image.setMaxHeight(50);
                image.setMaxWidth(50);
                image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                option.inSampleSize = 2;
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root.getPath() + "/"
                        + imageName,option);
                image.setImageBitmap(bm);
                linearImageView.addView(image);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

    }
```

Comment: Your codes only show files from folder `MYPICS` right?

Comment: Yes but you can change it as per your need.