# how to add images in array from sd card instead of drawable

Tags: android, arrays, android-imageview, android-sdcard

i am working on a image GridView app in which i am adding images in array from drawable, but now i want to add images in array from sd card.

note: i want to add images from specific folder like: `"sdcard/android/data/com.example.images"`

**GridView Class**

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ImageAdapter Class:**

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;



    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            // R.string.http_icons_iconarchive_com_icons_martz90_circle_512_android_icon_png
            R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2, R.drawable.pic_3,
            R.drawable.pic_4, R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
            R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8, R.drawable.pic_9,
            R.drawable.pic_10, R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
            R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14, R.drawable.pic_15 };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

example of what i want:

```
// Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {          
// how to add images from sd card here
 };
```

how do i add images to array from sd card instead of drawable.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039779/displaying-images-from-a-specific-folder-on-the-sdcard-using-a-gridview

Comment: can you help me with my code or give me sample because i am not understanding

Answer (score 0):

Just put all filenames from that specific folder in a `ArrayList<String>`. Then change getView() a bit to let the ImageView load from file.

Comment: can you help me with my code or give me sample because i am not understanding

Comment: Yes i can help you. Please show your code. Explain what you do not understand to begin with.

Comment: i updated my code please see and help me to add images from sd card to array `public Integer[] mThumbIds = { //add images from sd card }`

Comment: That code was already there before i posted my answer. So you are repeating yourself only. That code is wrong as you cannot represent image filenames by integer values like for drawable resources. So take a String ArrayList as I proposed.

Comment: hey i found this : http://karanbalkar.com/2014/05/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in-android/ 

now will u help me to adjust this code with my code.

Comment: Throw away your code and take all the code from that site and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Drawable from a Bitmap, you should check out a library like "Universal Image Loader" and then use

> Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);